# Android browser doesn't see Fiddler proxy

Tags: android, windows, proxy, vpn

I have a problem when connecting Fiddler and my mobile with Android 9.
I installed Fiddler (tried on Windows 7 and Windows 10) and configured it with "allow remote connections". Then configured Android device from
https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid
Both the computer and the device are at the same network with router (wifi and cable for the computer). I use VPN. Router passes VPN connections (I see necessary sites on the computer and the device with strongSwan).

Restarted Fiddler and reconnected wifi on the device. Wifi icon is "Connected".

Through VPN I get a special part of the site configured in hosts.
Like 10.10.10.10 firstsite.com www.firstsite.com secondsite.com

On Windows when I enter firstsite.com it goes to 10.10.10.10. This is correct.
On Android when I enter firstsite.com it goes to firstsite.com, but I need it to go to 10.10.10.10.

Fiddler folder is in firewall exceptions. IP is static.

Please, help me. I tried many things found in Google but without success.

Comment: I was advised https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55154263/do-not-use-proxy-on-android-9-pie I will try and write the result.

Answer (score 0):

Works on Windows 10. Very wild thing: when setting wifi it is necessary to delete wifi and then setup proxy and port then password and then connect. Connect vpn on the computer and the device. If no luck restart computer, fiddler and the device (don't forget to turn on vpn). After it I was able to open the necessary site 10.10.10.10 on Android 9 pie.